# Emulating CSS Popup Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to emulate the popup box on this site when you mouseover "work" link: http://zooadvertising.com.au/

The popup and mouseover elements work great. The only thing I cannot figure out how to do is create multiple columns within the popped up element. When I try to add another div within it to say, float right as a second column, it creates more popups instead. Is there a way to nest divs inside an element styled like this?

Edited Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZE8q/6/

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" title="">
.NameHighlights {
position:relative;
}
.NameHighlights div {
display: none;
}
.NameHighlightsHover {
position:relative;
}
.NameHighlightsHover div {
display:block;
position:absolute;
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
top:30px;
left:-300px;
z-index:1000;
background-color: #000000;
padding: 15px;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: a jsfiddle would be nice here...when you paste ton of code, you tend not to get a lot of help because no one wants to read it all and guess what its currently doing

Comment: Let me get to work on that, my apologies

Comment: Updated with Fiddle showing what I currently have, and cannot seem to get past.

Comment: Really all I am asking is how to nest another div in the popped-up div, citing an example of someone who did it right so it can be visualized. I just don't know how to approach nesting another div within the popup. I am not sure how that is asking for you to "code the entire thing for me like this site".

Comment: so if i understand correctly, when you go to hover over another link inside the div that comes up you get another popup div?

Comment: Yes. For example, here is the updated version: I tried to add a border top style on a small div around the products to create an underline effect, but it creates a whole new div using the same spacing and positioning as the main div. http://jsfiddle.net/7ZE8q/6/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/7ZE8q/7/

you should oganize it un unordered list <ul> and <li> see my changes let me know if that works so i can post it as an answer

Comment: oops, wrong link i edited it to the new one.

Comment: @Asad Geez. Was I drunk or what? I meant it the other way round. You're right of course. I'll have to correct that.

Comment: FYI. Putting **DIV** (a block element) inside **SPAN** (an inline element) is even in HTML5 an invalid thing to do. Hence, you shouldn't - strictly speaking - do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution: [It's in JSFiddle Form](http://jsfiddle.net/tpressley1/e7WDm/41/). Hope this Helps. I used bootstrap to help add a bit of basic styling, but the important part isn't using bootstrap, it's the jquery used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.nav3Hov').hide();
        $('#nav3').on('mouseover', function(){
            $('.nav3Hov').stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
        }).on('mouseleave', function(){
            $('.nav3Hov').stop(true).delay(200).fadeOut(200);
        });      
        $('.nav3Hov').on('mouseenter', function(){
            $(this).stop(true).clearQueue().show();
        }).on('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).delay(200).fadeOut(200);
        });
});
```

**EDIT**
By the way, sorry for not using the jsfiddle that you provided. I started answering before you added it! :P

Comment: No, this is very clean and simple, you certainly did better than what I had. This retains the aesthetic of the jquery smoothing and timing while still leaving it quite editable with primarily HTML/CSS. If only I could up-vote you somehow.

Comment: Actually, interestingly enough when I take this out of the jsfiddle environment, it doesn't seem to work. It styles the popup menus properly but it is not hidden, it is omnipresent. In addition, the main <UL> list (the inline one) is not accepting the inline parameters. What could be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: @TDouglas, you are calling the jquery .hide() method on the pop-up upon ready document, right?

Comment: jsfiddle automatically tosses jquery inside a $(document).ready(function(){}).

Comment: @TDouglas Did you ever figure out the jsfiddle discrepancy? if so, and i was right, help a brother out by 1-upping his comment!

Comment: I stuffed it all into a single HTML and this is what is happening: http://yooskins.com/test.html    P.S. I have enough rep to upvote now and I did so :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26834/discussion-between-todd-and-tdouglas)

Comment: @TDouglas don't know if you caught that. include jquery in header of page, before your jquery scripts. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I got it working! Thank you for your help on this. You really helped.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8X3uj/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="top_bar">
  <span>Work
    <div class="popup">
      <div class="column" style="background-color: red;">
        <div class="left_column"></div>
        <div class="right_column"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color: green;">
        <div class="left_column"></div>
        <div class="right_column"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <div class="left_column"></div>
        <div class="right_column"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top_bar{ background-color: lightgreen; }
.popup{ background-color: black; height: 500px; display: none; font-size: 0px; }
.popup:hover{ display: block; text-align: center; }
.top_bar > span:hover > div{ display: block; }
.column{ height: 400px; width: 33%; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 1px; }
.column > div{ width: 50%; height: 300px; display: inline-block; }
.column > div:first-child{ background-color: dodgerblue; }
.column > div:last-child{  background-color: gray; }
```

1. The popup itself has black background.
2. There are 3 main columns inside the popup, with background red, green and yellow.
3. There are subcolumns inside each column, with background blue and gray.

You don't need any JS... just HTML and CSS, with :hover and display: inline-block;

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nicely done with plain CSS! The only issue I see is that if the user tries to hover the appearing bit too quickly, it disappears.

Comment: This was very clean, although I had some issues displaying text in the columns for some reason. This helped me understand a bit better what I was doing as you simplified it really down to the core concepts for me. Thanks!